# File uploading with ajax and progressbar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do file upload using ajax and the file is getting upload properly but the problem is i want to show the progress of file upload.

```
<input type="file" onchange="fileupload(this)" name="song" class="form-control" id="file">
<div id="uploaded_image"><progress id="progress" style="width: 100%;" value="0" max="100"></progress></div>
function fileupload(filee){
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("file", filee.files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url:root+"upload.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data)
        {
            if(data=='valid'){
                $('#uploaded_image').html("Ho gyiii");
            }else if(data=='not valid'){
                $('#uploaded_image').html("nhi Ho gyiii");

            }
        }
    });
}
```

How set progress value dynamically?

I found this somewhere and it's not working and i am not able to understand this

```
$.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

            // Upload progress
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total)*100;
                    //Do something with upload progress
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                }
           }, false);

           // Download progress
           xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
               if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                   var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                   // Do something with download progress
                   alert(percentComplete);
               }
           }, false);

           return xhr;
        },
        url:root+"upload.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data)
        {
            if(data=='valid'){
                $('#uploaded_image').html("Ho gyiii");
            }else if(data=='not valid'){
                $('#uploaded_image').html("nhi Ho gyiii");

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below example.

**Please replace below values to your values**

```
//your div for showing percent
<div class="progress_bar_in"></div>

//start spinner
$.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    dataType: dataType,
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    timeout: 60000,
    success: function (response) {
        //stop spinner
        $('.progress_bar_in').html('');
    },
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                let percentage = Math.round(percentComplete * 100);
                console.log(percentage);
                progressBar = `${percentage}`;
                if(percentage >= 100){
                    progressBar = `File reached server and Show some msg till we get response from server`;
                }
                $('.progress_bar_in').html(progressBar);
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        $('.progress_bar_in').html('');
    },
});
```

Comment: You should really look into using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API since `xhr` is very old and deprecated